# power spectrum by numpy.fft.fft

Tags: python, numpy, signal-processing, fft

The figure I plot via the code below is just a peak around ZERO, no matter how I change the data. My data is just one column which records every timing points of some kind of signal. Is the `time_step` a value I should define according to the interval of two neighbouring points in my data?

```
data=np.loadtxt("timesequence",delimiter=",",usecols=(0,),unpack=True)

ps = np.abs(np.fft.fft(data))**2
time_step = 1

freqs = np.fft.fftfreq(data.size, time_step)
idx   = np.argsort(freqs)

pl.plot(freqs[idx], ps[idx])
pl.show()
```

Comment: Yes, `time_step` should be the timing difference between `data[i+1]` and `data[i]`.  That is, if you have two arrays, `t` and `data`, then `time_step = t[1] - t[0]`.  It just ends up being a multiplier for `freqs`, so if your output has unexpected form, this probably isn't the problem, as it would just scale it.

Comment: if the data is like [1,2,3,4,5...1000],I mean in the perfect scenario,I receive a signal every second,there should be a peak around 1,right?

Comment: @questionhang If the data is Y=1,2,3,4,5... there is no periodicity in the signal. FFT measures signals that repeat, and the peaks in the power spectrum indicate how often they repeat. Now the signal `sin(Y)` _would_ have a peak...

Comment: The data I give to numpy.fft are not the timing points I receive the signal?

Comment: That means that your _f(t) = t_, and the fourier transform of that is the _first derivative_ of the dirac delta.  If you receive a signal at each timestep, then `data = [1, 1, 1, 1]` is what your _signal_ should be for an `fft`

Comment: @questionhang No, I think that is your problem. `fft` takes the _signal_ and you can you use `fftfreq` to get transform the timing points to get the frequency axis on your power spectrum plot. I've provided an example for you that does this.

Comment: I make two columns.One column is like [1,1,1,1,,..1] and the other is like [1,2,3,4,5]. The results are the same,a peak around zero.

Comment: If your signal is not approximately symmetric around 0, then it's normal to have a high DC component (index 0 of the fft). Try pre-conditioning your signal by subtracting the average value of all the samples, so that you have approximately as much positive "energy" as negative...

Comment: you revised my code,but the result is still a peak around zero.sigh

Comment: Is your data vector 1,2,...1000?    Even if it is 0,..999 the fft will be nearly the same.  You are taking the fft of a monotonically increasing (step) function and the fft will give a peak at the 0 Hz bin.  Even if you do the fft of 1000, ... 2000 the peak will still be at 0Hz.  The only difference will be the magnitude of the peak as the average value changed from 500, to 1500.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As others have hinted at your signals must have a large nonzero component. A peak at 0 (DC) indicates the average value of your signal.  This is derived from the Fourier transform itself.  This cosine function cos(0)*ps(0) indicates a measure of the average value of the signal.  Other Fourier transform components are cosine waves of varying amplitude which show frequency content at those values.

Note that stationary signals will not have a large DC component as they are already zero mean signals.  If you do not want a large DC component then you should compute the mean of your signal and subtract values from that.  Regardless of whether your data is 0,...,999 or 1,...,1000, or even 1000, ..., 2000 you will get a peak at 0Hz.  The only difference will be the magnitude of the peak since it measures the average value.

```
data1 = arange(1000)
data2 = arange(1000)+1000
dataTransformed3 = data - mean(data)
data4 = numpy.zeros(1000)
data4[::10] = 1 #simulate a photon counter where a 1 indicates a photon came in at time indexed by array. 
# we could assume that the sample rate was 10 Hz for example
ps1 = np.abs(np.fft.fft(data))**2
ps2 = np.abs(np.fft.fft(data))**2
ps3 = np.abs(np.fft.fft(dataTransformed))**2

figure()
plot(ps1) #shows the peak at 0 Hz
figure()
plot(ps2) #shows the peak at 0 Hz
figure()
plot(ps3) #shows the peak at 1 Hz this is because we removed the mean value but since
#the function is a step function the next largest component is the 1 Hz cosine wave.
#notice the order of magnitude difference in the two plots.
```

Comment: My data is arrival time for a series of photons. If single photon arrives uniformly,say,one count per second,  a period does exist and it is one second?  If photons do not arrive uniformly, I should define a signal intensity by myself?

Comment: Fascinating use case.  I think in either case you are ok.  In the end your data array should probably not be arange(1000), but should be something like: data = zeros(1000); data[::10] =1   This will indicate that once per second (assuming a sample rate of 10Hz - every 10th value a photon comes in) a photon comes in.  The deviation from this you can then measure either directly or wrt the "ideal" photon rate.

Comment: I'm not even sure it's a meaningful use case.  Sounds like OP wants something like `hist(diff(arrival_times))` and is just throwing an FFT at it because "I heard FFTs have to do with frequency or something".

Answer (score 2):

Here is a bare-bones example that shows input and output with a peak as you'd expect it:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.fftpack import rfft, irfft, fftfreq

time   = np.linspace(0,10,2000)
signal = np.cos(5*np.pi*time)

W = fftfreq(signal.size, d=time[1]-time[0])
f_signal = rfft(signal)

import pylab as plt
plt.subplot(121)
plt.plot(time,signal)
plt.subplot(122)
plt.plot(W,f_signal)
plt.xlim(0,10)
plt.show()
```

[image]

I use `rfft` since, more than likely, your input signal is from a physical data source and as such is real.

Comment: yes,my input signal is from a physical source.A cos singal is easy to plot. For a series of timing points,what should  signal = np.cos(5*np.pi*time) change  to?

Comment: @questionhang Signal is your input data, if it is not periodic, you _won't_ see a peak in the power spectrum (except maybe at 0). Your timing points should match with my variable `time` and your physical signal, measured from your device should be my variable `signal`.

Comment: I get one count every second.It should be periodic.The intensity is scaled by  count/s and the intensity is the same all the time in this perfect scenario.

Comment: Both plt.plot(time,signal) and plt.plot(W,f_signal) depend on the definition of signal.

Comment: if signal is a constant and  
W = fftfreq(signal.size, d=time[1]-time[0]), then plt.plot(W,f_signal) is determined. That means the timing points do not matter?

Comment: if your subplot(122),the peak should be around 2pi/5pi=0.4?

Comment: you gave an expression of signal = np.cos(5*np.pi*time) .If I receive a photon every second,what should it be like? The signal is periodic? I should collect the photon number in every time bin?

Answer (score 0):

If you make your data all positive:

```
ps = np.abs(np.fft.fft(data))**2
time_step = 1
```

then most probably you will create a large 'DC', or 0 Hz component. So if your actual data has little amplitude, compared to that component, it will disappear from the plot, by the autoscaling feature.