# FFT on the csv data gives peak at 0

Tags: python, csv, fft

I have a dataset a csv file representing a wave like shown below. I would like to find the frequency of oscillations, so I have done fft. But the output of fft is peak at zero. I am new to python and fft. So I am not sure what I am doing wrong.
The data is captured at 300Hz(300 data points in one second). The data set contains 6317 values.
[image1]

[image: 1]

Every peak has a wave following it. Here is an example at data points from 250 to 350
[image2]

[image: 2]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv
import numpy as np
csvfile=open('./abc.csv')
csvreader=csv.reader(csvfile)
readdata=next(csvreader)
csvfile.close()

data=np.array([readdata],dtype='float')
data1=data.reshape(6317,)

sp = np.fft.fft(data1)
sp_mag=np.abs(sp)/data1.size

freq = np.fft.fftfreq(data1.shape[-1])

plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.plot(data1)

plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.plot(freq,sp_mag)

plt.show()
```

The csv is available [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CejIz6AQK6IDEboeGPPDfaOzYPaiuz9V/view?usp=sharing) .
The frequency associated with first three and next 3 peaks is same. So in fft i expect two peaks t different frequency.

Any help is really appreciated. Kindly let me know if any other data is needed to answer this question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [power spectrum by numpy.fft.fft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20074930/power-spectrum-by-numpy-fft-fft)

Answer (score 0):

The value of the FFT at 0 is proportional to the sum of the data.  Probably the easiest fix is to subtract off the mean of the data before taking the FFT (assuming you don't care about the constant offset).

Adopting the notation from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform)

```
X[m] = sum[ x[n]*exp(-i*2*pi*n*m/N) ]
```

(X is the FFT, x is the original data)

For `m=0`, the exponential factors are all `==1`, so `X[0] == sum[x[n]]` (for this convention on where to put the normalization factors).